# How "pointer" function works? And *p condition?

Tags: arrays, c, function, pointers

I can't understand what kind of function is this and how it works?
Also what is the *p condition in for loop? What does he do?

```
char *uppercase(char *s) 
{
    for(char *p = s; *p; ++p) 
    {
        if ('a' <= *p && *p <= 'z')
            *p = *p - 32;
    }

    return s;
}
```

I can't call it like uppercase("any string") and that char *uppercase is confusing me.

Comment: A pointer type is still a type, in your case, a `char *` type.

Comment: There are no kinds of functions. This is just: a function

Comment: Strings in C are `char` _arrays_. The convention is that there is an "end of string" _sentinel_ value that is 0x00. The `*p;` is the loop's way of stopping when the EOS sentinel is detected (i.e. the end of the string is reached). It continues the loop only _if_ the current character is _not_ the sentinel. `*p;` is shorthand for `*p != 0;`

Comment: Worth mentioning is that you can pass in an array name only, not a pointer to a constant string.

Comment: @Ron How can I pass a constant string ?

Comment: @Bobamas You can not pass in a pointer to a constant string to your function, as your function modifies a pointed-to data. Trying to modify a constant, pointed-to string is UB. So, passing in a pointer defined as `char* c = "Hello World";` is UB. Passing in a char array name defined as `char c[] = "Hello World";` is ok.

Comment: @Bobamas ***`I can call it like uppercase("any string")`*** - no you can't. This example invokes an\ Undefined Behaviour

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`char *uppercase(char *s)` declares `uppercase` to be a function with a parameter `s` of type `char *` and that returns a `char *`. (`char *` means a type that is a a pointer to a `char` object in memory.)

`for(char *p = s; *p; ++p)` defines a `char *` named `p` and initializes it to `s`. So, when this loop starts, `p` is pointing to the same place that `s` points to. The second item, `*p`, says to continue the loop as long as `*p` is not zero. (`*p` is the `char` that `p` currently points to.) The third item, `++p` says to increment `p` by one on each iteration. This causes `p` to point to the next `char` in memory.

`if ('a' <= *p && *p <= 'z')` is a non-portable test for whether `p` is a lowercase letter. The C standard does not guarantee that the codes for the lowercase letters `a` to `z` are between the values of the codes for `a` and `z` or that there are not any other codes in between them. The proper way to write this is `if (islower((unsigned char) *p))`.

`*p = *p - 32;` is a bad way to change a code for a lowercase letter to the code for the corresponding uppercase letter. It is bad because it relies on the difference between the codes for these letters being 32. That is a feature of ASCII, but the C standard does not guarantee this. `*p += 'A' - 'a';` would be a slightly better way to write this, but the C standard provides a better way: `*p = toupper(*p);`.

This `islower` and `toupper` functions are declared in the header `<ctype.h>`. (Note: Using `toupper` with characters that are not known to be in the basic execution character set requires converting its input to `unsigned char` and dealing with the fact that its output value may overflow a `char`. Since this source code is applying `toupper` only to characters already known to be lowercase letters, which are in the basic execution character set, this is not a problem.)

In summary, the function will examine each character in the string pointed to by `s` and change all the lowercase letters to uppercase letters.

Comment: Omg Thank you so much for this smoothest explanation!! If i wanna make this function null safe does if(*s == NULL){ return 1;} enough?

Comment: @Bobamas: If the function is called with a null argument, it should declare an error (possibly print a message and exit the program, or call some error-handling routine or trigger a signal) and/or return a null pointer. It should not return 1. (You can use `return 0;` to return a null pointer, or `return (void *) 0;` to be clearer about the intent, or `return NULL;` if a suitable header is included.)

Comment: @Bobamas remember you can't use it like this `uppercase("hello world");`

Comment: @P__JsupportswomeninPoland Is there any solutions for using like that ?

Comment: You need to allocate a new char array to store the result.

Comment: I think a lot about that but cant figure it out how to store the result

Comment: static variable, malloc